# Is "the same" widely used in any native-speaking population of English speakers?

Tags: dialects, subcontinental-english

I often see "the same" used regularly in discourse from and among South Asian speakers of English, particularly among speakers of IndE, as in

> *I visited the tiger preserve in Ranthambore, and I highly recommend **the same***.

But in my experience with speakers of American and British English, it's hardly ever used.

Is there any population of native speakers of English (i.e. populations who have English as their first, and typically only, language<sup>1</sup>) which uses this construction regularly? Perhaps in some sub-population of Britain or one of its historical colonies, like Australia, New Zealand, et al?

Or is this principally an IndE usage?

<sub>**NB:** I'm particularly looking for authoritative references, perhaps from corpora, academic studies, or other reference works, rather than anecdotal data.</sub>

Comment: Usages like this are never going to be particularly common, irrespective of exactly how they're phrased, so I don't think it's likely there would be any concept of "isolated linguistic pockets" where unusual variations survive over extended periods of time in *totally* Anglophone communities. My guess is it's just another example of "Indian English" where relatively few people are anywhere near *native* speakers. I imagine the reason such "Victorian" usages often survive in IE is simply that more speakers there get much of their exposure to English from (on average, *old*) texts.

Comment: (Just a guess, but might it be that Hindi doesn't have an equivalent to the way most Anglophones would use ***it*** in such contexts today?)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your suspicions mirror my own, but I asked the question to see if I could get confirmation, or any other interesting tidbits. Though in re: isolated linguistic pockets retaining unusual usages, I think I've read here on EL&U that in Yorkshire or anywhere somewhere in England, people still regularly use *thee* and *thou*?

Comment: Noted that you're not after anecdotal comments - but I'm native BrE, and I'd certainly use this in what appears to be a very similar context. Is your question thus  really probing the lack of "doing"/"that you do" or similar?

Comment: @ProfYaffle You'd use "the same" in contexts where you could equally substitute the pronoun *it*? Interesting. What area are you from? Do others do the same? (See what I did there?) Anecdotal evidence is 100% kosher in comments; I'm happy to have it. Also I didn't quite grok your question about "doing".

Comment: @Dan: But *thee* and *thou* are ***exactly*** the kind of really common words that *would* survive, since they (or more modern equivalents) are used by everyone many times every day. Nothing like *I commend the same to you*.

Comment: @DanBron Wales originally. The "doing" comment was regarding *I highly recommend **doing** the same* or ***that you do** the same*. And your use of *the same* in that comment looks 100% natural to me, as would anything like *oh, we watched the same* / *did the same* and similar.

Comment: @DanBron [If it's helpful](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/same_2) - specifically, definition 1 bullet 4 and definition 3.

Comment: @ProfYaffle Yes, I think I'll need to clarify better precisely the specific usage of "the same" I mean. It's a kind of anaphora, used where most Anglophone speakers would instead choose the pronoun *it*, and typically falls at or near the end of a sentence. You'd recognize it if you encountered it, and it's a different kind of usage from my "do others do the same" or your "doing the same thing you do". I'll have to collect more examples for contrast.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah, I understand your point better now. Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30000/using-the-expression-the-same-for-a-previously-mentioned-item

Comment: It is only an Indian English expression according to the following extract: ***"The same"*** - *This phrase drives me nuts! Rather than refer to something that has previously been referred to as “it”, “it” is referred to as “the same”.  Confused? Here is an example I saw recently:  “I do not understand what you mean, please revert regarding the same”* http://rakheeghelani.com/2012/10/15/indian-english-my-top-10/

Comment: @Josh61 That's worth an answer. I'd upvote you.

Comment: I was unaware that the usage was rare. In Australia it's not uncommon, although it tends to be used mostly in administrative correspondence as shorthand for "the thing I've previously referred to". I've also heard it without "the" - *please complete the ZZ form and forward same by close of business*.

Comment: Don't know that I believe it really is rare in the US; we sometimes say the same. "It" or "this" do seem more common.

Comment: @TheNate I have not experienced the same. But in any case, it's super common in InE. Comparatively, AmE and BrE wouldn't event show up on the nGram.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that none of the comments had considered the colonial factor. In India (I cannot speak for other ex-colonies), English was mainly introduced into the local population via British-run schools, and experience with the British-run administration (which naturally employed Indians who graduated from said schools). Moreover, English was also taught in these schools in a classical aspect, the way Latin and Greek were being taught at the colleges of Britain proper. So while vernacular oddities of grammar (so prolific in Englishes everywhere, anyway) cropped up in what is called "Indian English", a more formal, technical use of the language was (and is) seen as a natural exercise in articulation, a convenience of which a fluent speaker is obliged to take advantage. In short, English has long been seen as the language of education, and economic/legal function, so it's actually not surprising that it is deployed in a way which reflects that functionality. Read Aijaz Ahmad's In Theory for more, specifically the essay "Indian Literature: Notes Towards the Definition of a Category".

Comment: That's an excellent comment, but can you remark specifically on the usage of 'the same' to make this an answer?

Comment: @Mitch I can't account for that phrase specifically, but it certainly belongs to a family of word-saving unambiguous phrases - the latter property disqualifies the use of "it", at least in pre-21st century eras -  which are regularly used in administrative parlance. Also, I intended to enter that "answer" as a comment, but didn't have enough reputation at the time. * hides face in shame *