# What's the meaning of "the same" in Indian English

Tags: subcontinental-english

I work in tech, and at the company I work for employs and does business with a lot of Indian businesses and individuals. When exchanging emails, I've been noticing the use of "the same" in a completely different context than I'm familiar with.

To note a few examples, here are some phrases I've received:

> "Let's look at improving **the same**."
>
> "Could you please check for **the same**?"
>
> "He did tell me the results from yesterday but I need to check for
> **the same**"

The use seems a bit random, as sometimes there are no prior sentences to put "the same" in context, nor is there always a subject/issue/object in comparison when "the same" is used.

Can anyone clarify?

Comment: It's not just Indian English - I think it's business English in general.

Comment: It’s also legalese, but in legal documents it’s usually precisely clear to what “the same” refers, In these documents it refers to something or someone or a group previously defined, which is inelegant but not open to argument.

Comment: “*Yes, this is an expression that is common in Indian business English. It used to be common in UK business-speak too, but has gone out of fashion there - but not so on the subcontinent, apparently*” – **Jun 16 '11 at 9:08*** - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30000/using-the-expression-the-same-for-a-previously-mentioned-item

Answer (score 5):

You can think of "for the same" as "it".

> "Let's look at improving the same."

"Let's look at improving **it**."

> "Could you please check for the same?"

"Could you please check **it**?"

> "He did tell me the results from yesterday but I need to check for the
> same"

"He did tell me the results from yesterday but I need to check **it**"

Answer (score 2):

The matter previously referred to.

I'm not aware of the history behind this phrase, and I don't use it in my own emails, but I encounter it frequently.

> Let's look at improving the same.

What were they talking about before his sentence? Their ROI? If they were, they want to improve their ROI.

> Could you please check for the same

What were they talking about before his sentence? Whether a colleague had recieved their salary? In that case, the matter is the salary, and the sender wants you to check if you recieved yours.

> He did tell me the results from yesterday but I need to check for the same

The results. Either from yesterday, or today, I'm not sure, but "the same" is definitely referring to "the results" here.

Answer (score 0):

That is a translation from Indian languages. It is used in place of "this/that/the said matter or thing.

Comment: Do you have any references to back this up?